# Где происходит сжатие изображений при запросе с параметром?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, http

Приступил к оптимизации сайта, основные затраты - это, конечно же, изображения. Казалось бы, потребуется так или иначе сжать картинки на сервере, чтобы снизить передачу данных.

Но потом я узнал, что атрибуты ссылок на изображения поддерживают параметры размера. Например:

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg?width=800px">
```

Проверил, и правда клиент получает изображение на самом деле меньшего размера и весит меньше.

Но это вызывает вопрос, а что и где осуществляет сжатие и насколько это ресурсозатратно? Имеет ли смысл, пусть и в качестве костыля, просто модифицировать параметром ссылки вместо того чтобы на самом деле сжимать изображения?

Comment: Ваш сайт — вам виднее, что и где

Comment: То, что Вы написали - это просто передача GET-параметра, который обрабатывается на стороне сервера

Comment: Как костыль - сойдет. Как костыль под оптимизацию для поисковиков - нет, ответ будет долгий. Но это нагрузка неслабая если сервер эти ресайзы не кэширует.

Comment: @andreymal никакой логики работы с изображением на сервере не предусмотрено, поэтому виднее тут быть не может.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Могли бы рассказать подробнее почему это плохо для SEO? Я могу догадываться, но лучше знать.

Comment: @Leo240 Это понятно. Вопрос был о том насколько это ресурсоемко и целесообразно ли такое использовать на практике.

Comment: гугл оценивает отклик сервера, ответ при ресайзе может быть больше 500мс, что очень долго для него

Comment: @YesMan если никакой логики не предусмотрено, значит изображение сжиматься не будет. Вы сами себе противоречите и, видимо, чего-то не знаете о своём сайте

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev всё понятно, благодарю. Думаю, это можно считать ответом на вопрос. Напишите тоже самое как ответ чтобы я мог его отметить.

Comment: @andreymal напротив, как раз знаю и поэтому говорю, что никакой специально написанной логики нет. Тем не менее, клиент получает сжатое изображение если запрашивает его с параметром, значит где-то оно жмется.

Comment: @YesMan значит вы не знаете, что чего-то не знаете :) Вы можете описать полный путь прохождения и обработки HTTP-запроса во всех мыслимых подробностях с момента его получения сервером на сетевую карту до завершения отправки ответа?

Comment: @andreymal конечно нет, иначе бы не задавал эти вопросы.

Comment: @YesMan тогда ничем помочь не можем. Если сайт делали не вы, то спрашивайте не у нас, а у того, кто делал сайт. Если сайт делали вы, то значит расскажите, как вы его делали

Comment: @andreymal Если вы еще не поняли, вопрос общетеоретический и не привязан к какому-то конкретному решению. Если вы считаете, что пережатие происходит в где-то в рамках стандартного протокола HTTP, то расскажите об этом. Если у вас нет даже предположений, не понимаю зачем вы задаете эти вопросы.

Comment: @YesMan ну, в заголовке написано «Где происходит сжатие изображений при запросе с параметром?» — это никак не тянет на теоретический вопрос :) Предположениям появиться неоткуда, потому что вы категорически отказываетесь хотя бы примерно рассказать, что же у вас там на сайте творится. Если вы продолжите упрямиться, я буду голосовать за закрытие вопроса как слишком общего. «Что и где осуществляет сжатие» зависит только от того, как это сделает конкретный программист конкретного сайта. Ничего «общетеоретического» здесь ответить нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal  я уже говорил, что никакой специальной логики предшествующей отправке изображения, не реализовано, поэтому не понимаю почему вы продолжаете спрашивать о том, что там сделал программист. Отвечаю еще раз - ничего. Или вы имеете ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: @YesMan это невозможно, ни один существующий веб-сервер не станет сжимать картинки сам по себе, если его не попросить об этом явно. Если же, по вашим словам, никто ничего не делал, значит вы где-то врёте. Или картинки всё-таки на самом деле не сжимаются, или кто-то что-то делал - может, кодил в сайте, может, настраивал что-то такое, может, подключал специальный модуль (для IIS есть такой). Третьего не дано.

Comment: @andreymal теперь понятно о чем вы. Да, есть IIS, но он работает по-умолчанию, хотя, тем не менее, жать больше некому. И наверняка такой модуль установлен, раз уж жмет. Наименование подскажите?